# Are there two different notions of tensor densities?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, differential-forms

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1211616/775082) answer elucidates the definition of a tensor density, which serves as a "generalization" of differential forms to extend the theory of integration to non-orientable manifolds. Just for the sake of completeness, let me quote (from the answer above) the definition of a tensor density here. A density of **weight s** is a map $\mu:V\times V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, where $V$ is a real vector space, such that for all linear operators $A:V\rightarrow V$, the following holds.
$$\mu(AX_1,\dots,AX_n) = |\det A|^s\mu(X_1,\dots,X_n) \tag{1}\label{1}$$
with the obvious generalization to fields.
On the other hand, there is [another](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_density#Tensor_and_pseudotensor_densities) definition - more common in the Physics literature but also appearing on Ref. 1 - defining tensor densities based on their transformation law. For example, a *scalar* density $a$ of weight $s$ would transform, after a coordinate transformation with jacobian matrix $J$, as
$$a=|\det J|^s a'\tag{2}\label{2}$$
or
$$a=(\det J)^s a'\tag{3}\label{3}$$
the former if it's an even density and the latter if it's odd (or vice versa, the [wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_density) article and Spivak seem to say different things, but that's irrelevant here). The primes denote the object in the new coordinates (\eqref{4} should make it clear) These are also called relative scalars and relative tensors. A notable example is the determinant of the metric tensor, which in two different coordinate charts is
$$\det(g_{ij})=\det(\tilde{g}_{ij})\left[\det\frac{\partial\tilde{x}}{\partial x}\right]^2\tag{4}\label{4}$$

Now the question:

1. Are these constructions different things sharing the same name or are they related?
2. Given that $dx^1\wedge...\wedge dx^n=\det\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial \tilde{x}}\right) d\tilde{x}^{1}\wedge...\wedge d\tilde{x}^n$. Define $d^n x:=dx^1\wedge...\wedge dx^n$ and $d^n\tilde{x}:=d\tilde{x}^{1}\wedge...\wedge d\tilde{x}^n$. Would $d^nx=\det\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial \tilde{x}}\right) d^n\tilde{x}$ make it a density in the sense of \eqref{3}? Many Physics books (e.g. Carroll) assert $d^n x$ is a density for this reason$^1$.

---

Notes:

$^1$ <sub>The idea behind would be that by $d^n x$ they mean an object that has this form in *any* coordinate frame (which for a differential form isn't the case for general coordinate transformations).</sub>

References:

1. *A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry, Vol. 1*, M. Spivak. Page 134.

Comment: I'd say they are related, with $\bar{x}^i=A^i_jx^j$ the relation is figuratively speaking $\bar{\mu}(\bar{x}^i)=\det (A^i_j)\mu(x^i)$. Since $A$ is any linear map we can use one in particular, $A^i_j=\frac{\partial \bar{x}^i}{\partial x^j }$.  Finally with $J=\det (\frac{\partial\bar{x}^i }{\partial x^jl })$ $$\bar{\mu}(\bar{x}^i)=J\mu(x^j)$$