# Differential densities of rank $k<n$.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

**Motivation**

In "[Gelfand Transforms and Crofton formulas](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00029-007-0045-5)" the authors state that "Roughly speaking, densities are the most general objects that can be integrated over submanifolds independently of parameterization and orientation". So I wanted to understand these concepts better. There was a very good answer about densities (of rank $n$) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1210148/explain-densities-to-me-please/1211616?), and I was wondering how this extends to densities of rank $k$.

**Density of rank $k$**

In "[Gelfand Transforms and Crofton formulas](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00029-007-0045-5)" the authors define a $k$-density (a density of rank $k$, not to be confused with the weight) over a vector space $V$ as a continuous function $\phi:\underbrace{V\times\ldots\times V}_k\to\mathbb{R}$ such that for any set of $k$ linearly independent vectors $\{v_j\}_{j=1}^k$ and $A\in GL(k,\mathbb{R})$ we have
$$\phi(Av) = |\det A|\phi(v).$$
If I understood it correctly, the notation $Av$ means $(\sum_j A_{j1} v_j, \ldots, \sum_j A_{jk} v_j)$.

It is clear that for $k=n=\dim V$ this is just a usual (volume) density. For $k<n$, $\phi$ behaves like a density when restricted to any $k$-dimensional subspace of $V$. In fact it is less constrained than an $n$-density on the full space. Did I understand this correctly?

**Examples of $k$-densities: $|\alpha|$, $\langle \alpha, \beta\rangle$?**

Let $\alpha = \alpha_{i_1\ldots i_n} \, e^1\wedge\ldots \wedge e^n$ be a $n$-covector for an $n$-dimensional space. Then from $\alpha(Av) = (\det A) \,\alpha(v)$, and thus $|\alpha(Av)| = |\det A| \, |\alpha(v)|$ is a density. That is, it is enough to take the absolute value of an $n$-covector to get an $n$-density. If $V$ is a space over the complex numbers then $|z| = z^*z$. It's also clear that I can get a density of weight $s$ from $|\alpha|^s$.

Now let $\beta = \beta_{i_1\ldots i_n} \,e^1\wedge\ldots \wedge e^n$ then I believe the following object is an $n$-density of weight $2$:
$$\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle = \alpha^*_{i_1\ldots i_n}G_{i_1\ldots i_n}\beta_{i_1\ldots i_n} (e^1\wedge\ldots\wedge e^n)^*(e^1\wedge\ldots\wedge e^n) = \alpha^*_{i_1\ldots i_n}G_{i_1\ldots i_n}\beta_{i_1\ldots i_n}|e^1\wedge\ldots\wedge e^n|^2.$$
This should hold because
$$|(e^1\wedge\ldots \wedge e^n)(Av)|^2 = |\det A|^2\, |(e^1\wedge\ldots \wedge e^n)(v)|^2.$$

So if I want to consider $k<n$ I can try to see whether the above approaches work for $k$-densities.

**Proof that $|\alpha|$ is a $k$-density**

Let $\alpha = \sum_{|I|=k} \alpha_I \, (e^{i_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge e^{i_k})$. I want to show that $|\alpha(Av)| = |\det A| |\alpha(v)|$. I will show $\alpha(Av) = (\det A) \alpha(v)$ from which the former will follow.

Let $\{e_j\}_{j=1}^n$ be the basis of $V$ that is biorthogonal to the basis $\{e^i\}_{i=1}^n$ for $V^*$, biorthogonal meaning $e^i(e_j) = \delta^i_j$. Now let $\{v_r\}_{r=1}^k$ be $k$ vectors from $V$, then their coordinates with respect to $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n$ are given as the $n\times k$ matrix $C_{ij} = e^i(v_j)$. Then it follows that:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\alpha(Av) &= \sum_{|I|=k}\alpha_I \,(e^{i_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge e^{i_k})(Av)  \\
&=\sum_{|I|=k}\alpha_I \, \det C_IA \\
&= \sum_{|I|=k}\alpha_I \, \det C_I \det A \\
&= (\det A)\, \alpha(v).
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Here $C_I$ was the $k\times k$ submatrix of $C$ with rows from $I$ (in ascending order). Taking powers $|\alpha|^s$ results in a $k$-density of weight $s$.

**Proof that $\langle \alpha, \beta \rangle$ is a $k$-density**

Let $\alpha = \sum_{|I|=k} \alpha_I\, (e^{i_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge e^{i_k})$ and
$\beta = \sum_{|J|=k} \beta_J\, (e^{j_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge e^{j_k})$. I define their "inner product" by distributing the terms:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\langle \alpha, \beta\rangle
&= \left(\sum_{|I|=k}\alpha_I\,(e^{i_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge e^{i_k})\right)^*G
\left(\sum_{|J|=k}\beta_J\,(e^{j_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge e^{j_k})\right)\\
&= \sum_{|I|=k}\sum_{|J|=k} \alpha_I^*G_{I,J}\beta_J \, (e^{i_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge e^{i_k})^*(e^{j_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge e^{j_k}),
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $^*$ is complex conjugation. The product is to be understood pointwise and not as a wedge or something else, i.e.
$$\bigl((e^{i_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge e^{i_k})^*(e^{j_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge e^{j_k})\bigr)(v) = \bigl((e^{i_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge e^{i_k})(v)\bigr)^*\cdot\bigl((e^{j_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge e^{j_k})(v)\bigr),$$
where $\cdot$ is multiplication of complex numbers.

Now let $C_{ij} = e^i(v_j)$, then I can write:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\langle \alpha, \beta \rangle(Av)
&= \left(\sum_{|I|=k}\alpha_I \,(e^{i_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge e^{i_k})(Av)\right)^*G\left(\sum_{|J|=k}\beta_J \,(e^{j_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge e^{j_k})(Av)\right) \\
&= \left(\sum_{|I|=k}\det \alpha_I \,\det C_IA\right)^*G\left(\sum_{|J|=k}\det \beta_J \,\det C_JA\right) \\
&= \left(\sum_{|I|=k}\alpha_I \,\det C_I \det A\right)^*G\left(\sum_{|J|=k}\det \beta_J \,\det C_J \det A\right) \\
&= (\det A)^*(\det A)  \left(\sum_{|I|=k}\alpha_I \,(e^{i_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge e^{i_k})(v)\right)^*G\left(\sum_{|J|=k}\beta_J \,(e^{j_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge e^{j_k})(v)\right)  \\
&= |\det A|^2 \langle \alpha, \beta\rangle (v).
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

I can take powers $\langle \alpha,\beta\rangle^{s/2}$ to get densities with weight $s$. I should also be able to formulate a similar operation such as $\langle \alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_r\rangle$ by expanding things in a similar manner, which should yield a $k$-density of weight $r$ (provided $r$ is even).

**Interpretation**

If $|\omega|$ is indeed a density for $k<n$, then what would be the physical/geometrical meaning of it in an integration problem? For instance a $2$-form in 3D $\omega = \star (f_1dx + f_2 dy + f_3 dz)$ can be used to integrate surface flux given a vector field $f$. It results in $f\cdot \hat{n} dS$. The corresponding $2$-density $|\omega|$ then integrates  $|f\cdot \hat{n}|dS$, which is some kind of quantity that "doesn't care" about whether $f$ is in the positive or negative halfspace w.r.t. $n$ - it always takes the normal that would produce a positive result. Are there physical examples of something that would integrate like this over a surface? Some kind of non-oriented flux?

Densities of the form $\|\omega\|_2 = \sqrt{\langle \omega, \omega\rangle}$ should represent $k$-volume measure I believe. As an example for $k=1$ and $G_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$ I have $vol_1 = \sqrt{\sum_i (e^i)^2}$. So $G_{ij}$ here plays the role of metric tensor coefficients I guess, and the variants with more slots are some kinds of generalizations of this. I have no idea what $\langle \alpha, \beta\rangle$ for $\alpha\ne \beta$ is though.

**Double Cover and Densities**

Finally, if I were to integrate a $2$-form $\omega$ over the double cover of a non-orientable surface, e.g. a Mobius strip in $\mathbb{R}^3$, is it equivalent to twice the integral of $|\omega|$ or $\|\omega\|_2$ or some other $2$-density? Or is it something else? Is there a theorem about this anywhere?

More generally, is the correspondence: form $\to$ oriented manifold, pseudoform $\to$ potentially non-oriented but orientable manifold, density $\to$ potentially non-orientable manifold.

Comment: The generalization you might be looking for is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_on_a_manifold#s-densities_on_a_vector_space

Comment: N.b. $s$-densities in the sense of the link are sections of line bundles.

Comment: @TravisWillse Maybe I misunderstood something, but I think the link refers to densities of rank $n$, i.e. similar to what's explained in the answer from John Lee that I linked in the beginning of my question. I am trying to understand how densities of rank $k<n$ behave.

Comment: Without reading your post more carefully (time is limited a.t.m.) I suspect that what you're looking for can be realized as sections of $\left(\bigwedge^k T^*M\right) \otimes \mathcal E$ for some bundle $\mathcal E$ of $s$-densities for appropriate $s$.